# Sending data via jQuery Ajax as JSON to PHP Rest API with cURL

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest, api

I need to send some data to a REST API and include a custom header value. I try and echo out the data I am sending via the cURL script, but I get a blank page. 
Here is my HTML

```
<form id="RestData" action=Processor.php" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Update User" id="">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#RestData').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type:$('#RestData').attr('method'),
                url: form.action,
                data: {
                    email = $('#email').val();
                },
                beforeSend: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data.type == "error") {
                        //error handling
                    } else if(data.type == "success"){
                        //success handling
                    } 
                }
            });
                return false;
        },
        rules: {
            email: {
                required:true,
                email:true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

At this point, I am getting double quotes around my json array when I echo it out via the PHP processor

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $expired = NULL;
    $funded = TRUE;

    $data = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "expired" => $expired,
        "funded" => $funded
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

like this -> {"email":"test@test.com","expired":null,"funded":true}
I don't know if that will be an issue or not, any thoughts on how to remove if necessary?

With my final cURL code, nothing happens - blank screen and nothing in the network panel for a response.

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $expired = NULL;
    $funded = TRUE;

    $data = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "expired" => $expired,
        "funded" => $funded
    );

    $url = 'https://rest.api';

    $json_string = json_encode($data);

    $headers = array (
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: " .strlen($json_string),
        "Authorization: Bearer long token here"    
    );

    $channel = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    curl_exec($channel);
    $statusCode = curl_getInfo($channel, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($channel);    
    return $statusCode;
    echo $json_string;
?>
```

This is a little outside of my wheelhouse, I use cURL a lot, just not to a rest API. I know I should be getting a response back and am trying to echo it out on the page for debugging purposes, but I just get a blank page.

Comment: I don't understand your question about quote characters in the JSON. What do you perceive as a problem there?

Comment: return $statusCode;
    echo $json_string;   //this echo will never be called as it is after a return statement.

Comment: Per their API, this is what they expect the Body to be: {email:"test@test.com",expired:null,funded:true} I don't see quotes in there, so I assumed it would be an issue.

Comment: As pointed out by @Manpreet, that `return $statusCode` is about as useful as `exit;`. All execution will end there and nothing will be output to the HTTP response, hence your _"nothing in the network panel"_

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign that's not valid JSON. Can you link to the API documentation?

Comment: Here is the API documentation -> https://pastebin.com/wdYLGBbM

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign I'd say that's just a documentation bug. In JSON, keys and string values **must** be quoted

Comment: Thats what I thought, but don't know enough to state confidently!

Comment: None of the data that is submitted in the submitHandler is JSON.  Your making a normal post request and the data is being sent across in the post body as a query string.  That's not JSON.

Comment: @Taplar that's not the JSON data OP is talking about. They're basically proxying a standard POST request through to a remote JSON API. In any case, the real problem is solved below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the cURL response in a variable.

Secondly, you are doing echo after return statement, which will never execute.

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $expired = NULL;
    $funded = TRUE;

    $data = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "expired" => $expired,
        "funded" => $funded
    );

    $url = 'https://rest.api';

    $json_string = json_encode($data);

    $headers = array (
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: " .strlen($json_string),
        "Authorization: Bearer long token here"    
    );

    $channel = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    $response = curl_exec($channel);
    $statusCode = curl_getInfo($channel, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($channel);

    http_response_code($statusCode);
    if ( $statusCode != 200 ){
       echo "Status code: {$statusCode} \n".curl_error($channel);
    } else {
       echo $response;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'd use `http_response_code()` to set the response to that of the remote service. This way the JS side can use proper error handling for the AJAX call.

Comment: @Phil, thank you. Now I get "Status code: 500". Could this be tied to the "Authorization" header? The documentation just says "Authorization: Bearer (then a really long string)"?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign I think no. This is related to internal server error. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Now I get status code "0" so something is wrong on the API side I believe. Thank you Manpreet and @Phil for teaching me something new!

Comment: Also, the above code echo's $response, and I don't see that that variable exists

Comment: $response = curl_exec($channel);